# Flink 1.11.1 Cassandra Sink does not save when a timestamp is present

Tags: java, apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-flink

I'm not sure what the root issue is but this is the most basic I can make the problem. When I run something through kafka, and my streaming job picks it up, it runs through the entire process up until it's time to save it out to Cassandra, at which point it hangs. Any and all help is appreciated, been banging my head against this for too long

Snippets showing the basic problem below.

StreamingJob.java:

```
final DataStream<Pojo> stream = env.addSource(source)
    .process(new MyProcess());
CassandraSink.addSink(stream).setClusterBuilder(new ClusterBuilder() {
    @Override
    protected Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
        return builder.withCredentials("","")
            .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();
        }
    })
    .setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(false)})
    .setDefaultKeyspace("my_keyspace").build();

env.execute(jobConfig.getName());
```

MyProcess.java

```
@Override
Pojo myPojo = doSomethingtoMyInput();
out.collect(myPojo);
//Debugging this proves it works to this point
```

MyPojo.java

```
@Table(keyspace = "my_keyspace", name="my_table")
public class MyPojo {
    @PartitionKey(0)
    @Column
    String user_id;
    @PartitionKey(1)
    @Column
    String other_id;
    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column
    java.util.Date time_id;

    //Getters and setters using standard notation
}
```

My cassandra schema

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (user_id text,
    other_id text,
    time_idtimestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, other_id), time_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_id DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to verify the format of the `time_id` in the source as it might not be compatible with the CQL column.

In your POJO, you've mapped it to `java.util.Date` and if the field from the source does contain a date then it might be the reason it's not working.

CQL `timestamp` is a 64-bit signed int that represents the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch. The value of the field from the source can either be (a) an integer, or (b) a literal string that looks like `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm`. The list of valid ISO 8601 formats is available here -- [CQL timestamp](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html). Cheers!

Comment: Tried it with a string literal in that format, it still hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after much fighting. Flink and Cassandra is a very strict and tenuous connection. Everything must be perfectly aligned, decimal in Cassandra requires Decimal in Java, and more confusingly, the timestamp in Cassandra would only work with a long value in Java.

Hopefully this helps others who come across this same issue.